# Simplify converting lists to table in python

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a sample exercise of my code:

```
def printTable(data):
    colWidth = 8
    print(data[0][0].rjust(colWidth) + data[1][0].rjust(colWidth) + data[2][0].rjust(colWidth))
    print(data[0][1].rjust(colWidth) + data[1][1].rjust(colWidth) + data[2][1].rjust(colWidth))
    print(data[0][2].rjust(colWidth) + data[1][2].rjust(colWidth) + data[2][2].rjust(colWidth))
    print(data[0][3].rjust(colWidth) + data[1][3].rjust(colWidth) + data[2][3].rjust(colWidth))

tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
printTable(tableData)
```

How to simplify the printTable function?

Comment: with a loop probably

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this function? Just printing the data in a tabular format sounds a little off. I think you can use `pandas` and create a `dataframe` from your dictionary data and then do all sort of things with the `dataframe`.

Comment: I just want to print it in a table format and simplify the code repetition in the function with a loop or any method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

**With Pandas**

Try with pandas module. You can perform a lot of operations on tabuler data using pandas library. link for [Pandas documentation](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/)

see below example.

```
import pandas as pd

tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

df = pd.DataFrame(tableData)  #convert tableData to pandas dataframe
df = df.transpose()  #converting rows to columns
df.columns = ["Fruits", "Persons", "Animals"]  #adding headers to columns
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Fruits Persons Animals
0    apples   Alice    dogs
1   oranges     Bob    cats
2  cherries   Carol   moose
3    banana   David   goose
```

**Without Pandas**

You can simply transpose the tableData and print it in table format with see below example.

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
         ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
         ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

new = [list(i) for i in zip(*tableData)]   #list comprehension for transposing tableData

for i in new:
    print(*i)   #printing in table format
```

Output:

```
apples Alice dogs
oranges Bob cats
cherries Carol moose
banana David goose
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll add pandas to my module collection. It's much easier in handling tabular data.